# How to get a nested and optional object value with a default value and define type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Should be a simple one... I just want to get `data.user.roles`, but `data` could be empty. In that case, I need an empty array as result. Also I need to define the type of `user` - which is in this case `any`.
So this is, what I came up with:

```
const { data } = useSession()
const user: any = data?.user || {} // define user
const roles = user?.roles || []
```

It works, but it doesn't feel very smart.

And I am not quite sure, if this would work if `useSession` doesn't return full dataset:

```
type Session = {
  data: {
    user?: {
        roles?: string[]
    }
  }
}
const {
  data: {
    user: { roles = [] }
  }
}: Session = useSession()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is guaranteed to exist according to the `Session` type, so you don't need a `?` after that. From there you just drill in and provide a fallback at the end.

```
const { data } = useSession()
const roles = data.user?.roles ?? []
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyhDO8CWB7AdlAvFA3gWACgooATAQ2DIC5dDjiBXeCAJwH4b8j6eWUAbBByjxgLJGgDmAbQC6degF8FygqsIB6DVAC2KAMYBrKEwhxEqDADMGafcEuESEffzItoNuw-Qnm55HQACgBKGgDHAkJ9dFFcUgoyKEUsPzMEQLRQ6NjgKD5BeFTySgA6U3ZSgoQoNjYoOSgtETEJGVkgA)